# Python - SCP vs SSH for multiple computers and multiple files

Tags: python, ssh, scp

Python 2.4.x  (cannot install any non-stock modules).

Question for you all. (assuming use of subprocess.popen)

Say you had 20 - 30 machines - each with 6 - 10 files on them that you needed to read into a variable.

Would you prefer to scp into each machine, once for each file (120 - 300 SCP commands total), reading each file after it's SCP'd down into a variable - then discarding the file.

Or - SSH into each machine, once for each file - reading the file into memory. (120 - 300 ssh commands total).

?

Unless there's some other way to grab all desired files in one shot per machine (files are named YYYYMMDD.HH.blah  - range would be given 20111023.00 - 20111023.23). - reading them into memory that I cannot think of?

Comment: You can copy whole directories with `scp` if you use the `-r` flag.

Comment: with potentially several dozen files in the directories, I'd prefer to just scp or read the needed range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of the file, you can possibly do something like:

```
...
files= "file1 file2 ..."
myvar = ""
for tm in machine_list
         myvar = myvar+ subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "user@" + tm, "/bin/cat " + files]);
...
```

file1 file2 etc are space delimited.  Assuming all are unix boxes you can /bin/cat them all in one shot from each machine.  (This is assuming that you are simply loading the ENTIRE content in one variable) variations of above.. SSH will be simpler to diagnose.

At least that's my thought.

### UPDATE

use something like

```
         myvar = myvar+Popen(["ssh", "user@" +tm ... ], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It occurs to me that you said that you only have access to python 2.4 then my solution won't work...  You should replace check_output with

Comment: I was just looking up why it wasn't working and came to the conclusion about 2.4 - heck this way works great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`scp` lets you:

1. Copy entire directories using the `-r` flag: `scp -r g0:labgroup/ .`
2. Specify a glob pattern: `scp 'g0:labgroup/assignment*.hs' .`
3. Specify multiple source files: `scp 'g0:labgroup/assignment1*' 'g0:labgroup/assignment2*' .`

Not sure what sort of globbing is supported, odds are it just uses the shell for this. I'm also not sure if it's smart enough to merge copies from the same server into one connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a remote command via `ssh` that uses `tar` to tar the files you want together (allowing the result to go to standard out), capture the output into a Python variable, then use Python's [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) module to split the files up again.  I'm not actually sure how `tarfile` works; you may have to put the read output into a file-like [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object before accessing it with `tarfile`.

This will save you a bit of time, since you'll only have to connect to each machine once, reducing time spent in ssh negotiation.  You also avoid having to use local disk storage, which could save a bit of time and/or energy — useful if you are running in laptop mode, or on a device with a limited file system.

If the network connection is relatively slow, you can speed things up further by using gzip or bzip compression; decompression is supported by `tarfile`.

Answer (score 0):

As an extra to Inerdia's answer, yes you can get scp to transfer multiple files in one connection, by using brace patterns:

```
scp "host:{path/to/file1,path/to/file2}" local_destination"
```

And you can use the normal goodies of brace patterns if your files have common prefixes or suffixes:

```
scp "host:path/to/{file1,file2}.thing" local_destination"
```

Note that the patterns are inside quotes, so they're not expanded by the shell before calling scp. I have a host with a noticeable connection delay, on which I created two empty files. Then executing the copy like the above (with the brace pattern quoted) resulted in a delay and then both files quickly transferred. When I left out the quotes, so the local shell expanded the braces into two separate `host:file` arguments to scp, then there was a noticeable delay before the first file and between the two files.

This suggests to me that Inerdia's suggestion of specifying multiple `host:file` arguments will *not* reuse the connection to transfer all the files, but using quoted brace patterns will.